# Tooltip background alternation

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

The single tooltip which shows different messages for different controls. Now the Problem is the background image is not fit/suitable to all messages. I supposed to call the draw event of the tooltip for custom size, Font etc.,

I able to successfully call the draw and Popup event of the tooltip for particular message but setting the generalized size for different messages(e.ToolTipText) is unknown to me.

```
public void tooltip_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    e.ToolTipSize = new Size(100, 100);
}
```

Kindly let me know anybody have any idea about it.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to change the tooltip size dynamically depends on the text size?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the size in the Popup event, like this:

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 200);
    }
```

result of my test is this, hope it's helpful to you.
[image: picture of result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I required the POPUP should exact match with the Message and I suppose to use the same tooltip for multiple messages, so it shouldn't be hardcore value like 100, 200 etc.

Comment: the tooltip control is able to give a suitable size according to your message, isn't it? otherwise, you could calculate your message's size by your self, then you also could change the size in Popup Event, you just need to give an proper size to replace the hardcore value.

Comment: I am using the same tooltip for multiple message. So hardcore value will not help for this issue.

Comment: no, although you use the same tooltip control for different messages, you need not to give the hard code values, you can give dynamic value in the Popup. but you need to calculate the size by yourself.

Comment: yes, this approach(as you mentioned) is also solve my issue. Thank you Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my Problem. The below code of POPUP event will change the tooltipsize according to the text size.

public void toolTip_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {

```
        using (Font f = new Font("Arial", 12f))
        {
            e.ToolTipSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(
                toolTips.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl), f);
        }
```